# spring boot logback-spring.xml maxFileSize not working with SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

I want to configure logging in spring boot application. I have configure **logback-spring.xml**. The sample of **logback-spring.xml** is located on [here](https://github.com/PiyushChaudhari/SampleFile/blob/master/logback-spring.xml) and sample of **application-dev.properties** file is located [here](https://github.com/PiyushChaudhari/SampleFile/blob/master/application-dev.properties) When I just try to run spring boot application get below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@5b7a5baa - Failed to invoke valueOf{} method in class [ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize] with value [{LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE}]
ERROR in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@2003496028 - maxFileSize property is mandatory.
```

If I replace `<maxFileSize>{LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE}</maxFileSize>` with `<maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>` application is running successfuuly

Comment: You are sure you have set these property?

Comment: Yes, I m 100% sure that my property value already set in LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE value

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for htis? I am running into this same issue. I have a property from application.yml. I have verified that it is coming into logback.xml (tried using it in the file name to confirm). But, it just doesn't work for those three elements - maxFileSize, maxHistory and totalSizeCap.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the variable in your log filename. If it ("50MB") shows up in the filename, you know for sure that it is set.

I ran into this problem with the variables set in my pom.xml for profile "dev". I was using a separate profile "test" for my tests so the "dev" variables were not being set.

Answer (score 0):

this will solve the issue. In logback.xml use $ with {attribute}
ex:- ${max.log.size}

```
make sure u have initialized max.log.size with values in application.properties.
It works!!
```